# Add a DOM element between two children

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-manipulation

I want to add a dom element between two children, specifically right before the last one.

```
<div id='parent'>
    <div class='nav-option'></div>
    <div class='nav-option'></div>
    <div class='nav-option'></div>
    {{I want to insert something here}}
    <div class='nav-option'></div>
</div>
```

Right now I am using the following code:

```
$('#add-account').click(function(event){                               
    $('#face').append('<div class="nav-select"></div>');
});
```

But alas this adds the element at the end.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.insertBefore. That's the method the you'll want to look at. I'm sure the answers that follow will use jQuery's version of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div.nav-option:last')
    .before('<div class="nav-select"></div>');
```

**Check these out to read more:**

- [`:last` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)
- [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [insertAfter()](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) or [insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)

Answer (score 0):

jquery has `.insertBefore` and `.insertAfter` that both do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('.nav-option:last').before('<div class="nav-select"></div>');
```